P and RP - what if a Turing machine accepts on almost all paths?
The Wikipedia page on the RP complexity class says:

An alternative characterization of RP that is sometimes easier to use is the set of problems recognizable by nondeterministic Turing machines where the machine accepts if and only if at least some constant fraction of the computation paths, independent of the input size, accept. NP on the other hand, needs only one accepting path, which could constitute an exponentially small fraction of the paths. This characterization makes the fact that RP is a subset of NP obvious.

Is there a term for the class of problems recognizable by nondeterministic Turing macihnes where the machine accepts if and only if almost all paths accept? (that is, all paths except a fraction that goes to $0$ as the problem size goes to $\infty$)

It's still RP - you can amplify 1/2 success probability to make it 1 - 1/n, which satisfies your condition.

@Dmitry I think the main question was not whether it is in RP, but rather if it is inside some subclass of RP, like ZPP.

@Highheath, yeah, and I'm saying that it's exactly RP, by the argument above. You can do this amplification for any problem from RP.

Aah, when you say it like that it's obvious - I don't know what I misunderstood at first. I know it is not part of the original question, but I wonder: How low must the probability for failure (as a function of $n$) be, then, for the resulting class to be contained in e.g. ZPP? I reckon that if the number of failing computation paths is bounded by a constant for all inputs, then the problem is in P, for example.
